# How to update a standard vim plugin?

Tags: git, vim, plugins, editor

I have a bunch of vim editor plugins, installed via pathogen. To update a plugin in that case (let say plugin: tmuxline), it is as simple as:

```
cd $HOME/.vim/bundle/tmuxline
git pull
```

But I have some plugins installed in plugin directory, just downloading the source code (example in case of simple & smart MRU plugin https://github.com/yegappan/mru/blob/master/plugin/mru.vim). I installed it with wget:

```
cd $HOME/.vim/plugin/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegappan/mru/master/plugin/mru.vim
```

In that case there is a way to get updates of new versions of plugin?

Comment: Use `git clone` instead of wget.  That way, you can just do `git pull` and bam, you have your updates.

Comment: Just like you did to install it: `$ wget ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, you've downloaded the plugin from GitHub, so you could have alternatively `git clone`'d the plugin into your `~/.vim/bundles/` directory, and then used `git pull`. That's probably the easiest way.

Not every plugin is developed on GitHub, though. For those published on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/), you can use the mirror at http://vim-scripts.org/

For plugins that only exist "somewhere" in downloadable form, you have to rely on manually redownloading (or a *cron* job that does this) via `wget`.

Comment: thx Ingo, in facts in case mentioned above (MRU is also on github), I just have to do: `cd ~/.vim/bundles/ ; git clone https://github.com/yegappan/mru.git` me stupid